# PHP: Assign avatar of the webmail server used

Tags: php, image, gmail

I'm doing a website for registration, in which I want to assign the webmail server avatar image used by the user (gmail, hotmail, etc). For example using gravatar realize managed as follows:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php print md5(strtolower(trim('email')))?>?d=imagendefault.jpg&s=150" />
```

I know that for gmail emails, I can use The Google Contacts API for Contact photo management toretrieve a contact's photo, send an authorized GET request to the contact's photo link URL.
The URL is of the form:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}
```

But I'm not sure what is the parameter 'contactid'. My question is .. there is some method to get the profile picture of live / msn / outlook / hotmail and gmail? and how I can know that it's contactid to do with Gmail. Or if there is any easier method where you do not have to copy the image directly to my server. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img src="https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/116018066779980863044?sz=100" width="100" height="100">`
No need to store the image on your server.

Now if you dont know how to get the user id a simple solution is use `https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/me` for the pic link ... and here you will need to pull the pic to your server...This will require the user previously being logged into google.

And to get the id you might find this of some help https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

Comment: I understand the solution that you indicate, but I want to be assigned depending on the email address of the person who registers, not mine

Comment: This will do it for the person who registers. As long as you write your code in a client side script like javascript. When the user comes to your page the me on the end of the link(`https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/me `) will be the clients pic. All you need to do after the img is pulled in is save it to your server. Example http://jsfiddle.net/nezyj/ will show a picture of the user if they are logged in to google. If you want a more dirrect method you will need to use the people get api link at the bottom of my above answer. This allows you to enter the email and get the pic link